# Change filename when upload to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to change the filename before I upload through WordPress thickbox in a plugin? I want to use an input on the plugin upload page as the name of the file, but can't seem to pass the variable and I'm not sure where to hook this. Is this even possible to do?

> init.php

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_filter' );
    function custom_upload_filter( $file ){
       /* $file['name'] = 'wordpress-is-awesome-' . $file['name'];
        return $file;*/
            $fileNameHere = $_POST["bv_product_num"];
            $file['name'] = 'new value';
                //return $file;
                exit(var_dump($fileNameHere));
        $fileNameHere = $_POST["bv_product"];

    }
```

> upload_my_product.php

```
bv_product_num="this";
if(bv_product_num)
            {

                tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?bv_product_num='+bv_product_num+'&type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
                return false;


            }else{          
            alert("nothing");
            }
```

Comment: It is possible, but probably a bit difficult to do, and requires good WordPress development knowledge.  Unless you have a few months to waste on this, you should hire someone to do it for you.  No one will do it for free.

Comment: Hi @JuliePelletier thanks for the reply. I have a pretty good knowledge. I just can't seem to wrap my head around the possible route to take or how to pass this 1 variable. I've included above my last attempt. I'm trying to hook into the `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` . I'm able to manually set the variable without issue. As far as grabbing the variable from my plugin page, I just can't seem to pass it.

Comment: It would probably imply modifying the plugin which is rarely a good idea as it will be complicated to deal with updates later on.